# From Redis streams get all the remaining pending(PEL) mesages from XPENDING

Tags: redis, redis-streams

I would like to receive all the pending messages from PEL(Pending entry list) for a given stream and a consumer group.

Problem is that XPENDING command has a mandatory count variable. But I don't know how many pending messages beforehand. I just want to list all the pending messages. So how to handle this properly ?

```
XPENDING mystream group55 - + 10
```

Comment: One way of getting message count is using "XPENDING <stream> <group>" command. This will give you the total amount of pending messages for each consumer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the output of
[XAUTOCLAIM](https://redis.io/commands/xautoclaim) as the input for [XACK](https://redis.io/commands/xack) instead of using XPENDING